# Definir altura máxima para Alert Dialog

Tags: android, listview, dialog

Meu dialog tem uma lista, e quando essa lista tem muitas entradas, o dialog corta os botões no meio, como na imagem :

[image: Dialog]

Como faço para definir uma altura máxima pra não ficar cortado desse jeito?

Código do dialog

```
public void deleteCategoria(int despesa){
    mAba = despesa;
    final CategoriaDAO dao = new CategoriaDAO(this);
    final List<Categoria> list = dao.getLista(despesa);
    ArrayAdapter<Categoria> aa = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_multichoice,list);
    final ListView lv = new ListView(this);
    lv.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    lv.setAdapter(aa);
    AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).
            setTitle("Apagar categorias");
    ab.setView(lv);
    ab.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            return;
        }
    });
    ab.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            int len = lv.getCount();
            SparseBooleanArray checked = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();

                for (int y = 0; y < len; y++) {
                    if (checked.get(y)) {
                        CategoriaDAO catDAO = new CategoriaDAO(getApplicationContext());
                        Categoria item = list.get(y);
                        catDAO.deletar(item);
                    }else if(checked.size() == 0){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selecione uma categoria", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            Intent intente = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CategoriaListActivity.class);
            intente.putExtra("aba", mAba);
            intente.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK + Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(intente);
        }
    });
    ab.show();
}
```

Comment: Não crie a *ListView* no código JAVA, mas sim  num *layout* em *XML*

Comment: Crio um layout normal igual xml de activity? como faço pra colocar no dialog? @ramaral

Comment: Crie como se fosse igual a uma *Activity* e use `ab.setContentView(R.layout.o_seu_layout);`.

Comment: Não tenho como setar um Content view, apenas setView @ramaral

Comment: Não reparei que estava a usar o *Builder*, vou postar uma resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como disse no comentário não crie a ListView no código JAVA, mas sim num layout em XML.

Crie o *layout* da mesma forma como se fosse ser utilizado numa *Activity*.

**dialog_list.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

No código faça o *inflate* dele e atribua-o ao *AlertDialog* usando o método `AlertDialog.Builder.setView()`:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_list, null);

//Obtém a referência a ListView
ListView lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);

lv.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
lv.setAdapter(aa);

AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
ab.setTitle("Apagar categorias")
  .setView(view);
....
....
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente @ramaral, Obrigado.